# Google Sheets: Remove column headers from a QUERY()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to eliminate (not hide) the column headings from the following QUERY(). The output from the =QUERY() must be in a single row.

```
=QUERY(myData!A:G, "Select SUM(E), SUM(F) WHERE D ='"&E11&"'")
```

The current output is shown in images #1 and #2 below. The desired output is shown in image #3. Thanks for any help you can offer.

**Image #1**

[image]

**Image #2**

[image]

**Image #3**

[image]

Comment: I found this over at stackoverflow [Google SpreadSheet Query: Can I remove column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897291/19171356) I've tested it and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove headers, you should refer to the data range `A2:G` rather than the full columns `A:G`, and explicitly set the `headers` parameter to zero.

Additionally, you need to use the `label` clause to omit automatic headers in any aggregated columns, like this:

```
=query( 
  myData!A$2:G, 
  "select sum(E), sum(F) 
   where D = '" & E11 & "' 
   label sum(E) '', sum(F) '' ", 
  0 
)
```

Comment: I did not find any difference or improvement between my formula and the one you recommended, neither as regards the columns, nor as regards the use of the third parameter of the QUERY () function. Those are additional unnecessary items.

Comment: Whether the two formulas give the same results depends on the data. When `headers` is missing, `query()` tries to guess the number of header rows, and may guess incorrectly. If it guesses incorrectly, values will be missing from the sum, or superfluous values will get included (in the event the headers contain numbers.) Ditto for a data range that includes rows that are not data but headers. Additionally, when `headers` is missing, and the column is mostly blank, `query()` may set the column type incorrectly. I see no reason to ignore these scenarios as that amounts to trying your luck.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical but when in doubt I prefer to believe your undisputed knowledge of the subject

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
=QUERY(myData!A:G, "Select SUM(E), SUM(F) WHERE D ='"&E11&"'label SUM(E) '', SUM(F) ''")
```